# can base current be far less than collector current?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I'm using an NPN transistor to pull the gate of a P-channel FET low. I'm driving the base with 3.3v and a 10k series resistor. I have a 100k resistor in series with the collector and the gate of the P-channel FET which is then pulled up to 5.4v with another 100k resistor. So my base current is about 20x my collector current. Any trouble with that?

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of [Electronics.StackExchange.com](https://electronics.stackexhcange.com)?

Comment: Kirchhoff's Voltage Law determines actual Collector current, so yes.

Comment: Can you please tell us the voltage at the upper end of R220 resistor?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I’m not sure how KVL answers my question, I think you mean KCL but that doesn’t tell me whether or not the transistor is conducting. That’s all a function of the transistors parameters.

Comment: @user8055 the top of R220 is 5.4v as stated in the original question.

Comment: No KVL.   You have 2 100k resistors in series.   Divide voltage by 200k and you will get maximum current, which will be microAmps.

Answer (score 1):

Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL) must be satisfied.

You are fixiated on:

$$ \beta = \frac {I_C}{I_B}$$

So $I_C$ must be larger than $I_B$, but this implies the transistor is operating in the active region.

KVL input side:

$$V_{BB} - V_{R_B} -V_{BE} = 0$$

$$I_B = \frac {V_{BB} - V_{BE}}{R_B} = \frac {3.3V - 0.7V}{10k\Omega} = 260 \mu A$$

KVL output side:

$$V_{CC} - V_{R_{C_1}} - V_{R_{C_2}} - V_{CE} = 0$$

$$I_C = \frac {V_{CC} - V_{CE}}{R_{C_1} + R_{C_2}}$$

If we assume $V_{CE} = 0$, we can get $I_{C_{Max}}$.

$$I_C = \frac {V_{CC}}{R_{C_1} + R_{C_2}} = \frac {5.4V}{100k\Omega + 100k\Omega} = 27 \mu A$$

So based upon biasing resistors, the maximum $I_C$ is 1/10 of $I_B$.  Transistor is in the cut-off region.

Comment: This is not at all what I'm looking for. All you did was verify what I said to begin with, that the base current is much greater than the collector current. I also did that math and that's why I'm here asking the question. Your math just assumes the transistor is conducting which was my only question.

Comment: So what are you looking for.  It is the math associated with your circuit.  There is no need for 100k resistors.

Comment: Just a yes or no answer. Do NPN BJT’s behave as expected with very small collector current in comparison to the base current? I did the same math but it assumes the BJT is on.

Comment: No.   If your transistor BE is forward biased,  transistor is on,  just no collector current.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @StainlessSteelRat the transistor is operating in the cut off region. Below is graph from the datasheet showing the relationship between $V_{CE}$, $I_B$ and $I_C$.

[image: Vce Ib and Ic relationship for 2SC4617]

---

References:

- [2SC4617G NPN Silicon General Purpose Amplifier Transistor](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2SC4617-D.PDF)